# Laravel cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I'm trying to set a foreign key constraint in laravel 5 with migrations I receive the error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1215 
>   Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table
>   `rittenregistratie` add co   nstraint
>   rittenregistratie_karakterrit_id_foreign foreign key
>   (`karakterrit_id`) references `karakterrit` (`id`) on    delete
>   cascade)   [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215
>   Cannot add foreign key constraint D:\wamp\www>

But I have now idea why??? The order of migrating is right so why do I receive this error? The table rittenregistratie has a foreign key called karakterrit_id this is the primary key in the table karakterrit.

This is my migration rittenregistratie:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rittenregistratie', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps('datum');
            $table->integer('beginstand');
            $table->integer('eindstand');
            $table->text('van');
            $table->text('naar');
            $table->text('bezoekadres');
            $table->text('geredenroute');
            $table->integer('karakterrit_id')->default(1);
            $table->text('toelichting');
            $table->integer('kilometerszakelijk');
            $table->integer('kilomteresprive'); 

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                        ->references('id')
                        ->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('karakterrit_id')
                        ->references('id')
                        ->on('karakterrit')
                        ->onDelete('cascade');    
        });
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: @jszobody this is Laravel

Comment: The error you are getting is a DB error. Which means you need to take a closer look at the DB to see why. See the answer on that other thread for tips on troubleshooting foreign key errors.

Comment: Specifically: your `karakterrit_id` column isn't unsigned. I'm willing to bet the primary key is unsigned, and that's your issue. (Described in the other SO thread).

Comment: Oke, thanks for your help. So you're saying that my primary key isn't set in my karakterrit table?

Comment: I'm saying `$table->integer('karakterrit_id')->default(1);` probably needs to be `$table->integer('karakterrit_id')->unsigned()->default(1);`

Comment: Thankyou! works, I'm just getting started with laravel. But could you perhaps explain what unsigned does?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Laravel. It has everything to do with the database requiring that a primary key column and a foreign key column match _exactly_.

Comment: Oke, thanks I will search more on the web about it!!!

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
$table->integer('karakterrit_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
```

Have you created the `users` Table and `karakterrit` that you used in your query. If you have both tables, check the creation date of the migration files they both should be created before other table that references them.

Another problem might be `MyISAM` which does not support. Instead use InnoDB

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE categories ENGINE = InnoDB');
```

Answer (score 2):

One common problem with even Laravel 8 is that the table on which the foreign_id is being set up is created earlier. So when migrations run, they run in order and can't find foreign id referenced table. If you see that happen to change the name of the second table to an earlier date and you are sorted.

So say rename 2020_12_04_081855_create_developers_table.php to 2020_12_03_081855_create_developers_table.php.

That will take care of it. Remember the date should be earlier than the first table.

Answer (score 1):

for the most of  the case the referenced column must be either primary key or have unique key from my findings

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8: I renamed my two migration files with the foreign key constraints to the latest date. This solved for me.